# ParseLiveQuery dotNet subscription

Tags: c#, parse-platform

I am trying to use ParseLiveQuery on C# ([parse-live-query-dotnet](https://github.com/JonMcPherson/parse-live-query-dotnet)) but I am having some hard-time on using a callback.

This is the VisualStudio suggestion:
[image]

I am not being able to pass the parameters correctly. How could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution:

```
private void subscribe()
{
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> liveQuery = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Object").WhereEqualTo("u", u);

    subscription = liveQueryClient.Subscribe<ParseObject>(liveQuery).HandleEvent(Parse.LiveQuery.Subscription.Event.Create, new Parse.LiveQuery.Subscription.EventCallback<ParseObject>(parseLiveQueryCallback));
}  

private void parseLiveQueryCallback(ParseQuery<ParseObject> q, ParseObject o)
{
    //Actions here
}
```